# Why would Flask be used with Reactjs for Restful APIs?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask

I have heard of people who use **Flask** with **Reactjs** to build REST APIs. However, I am very confused by why Flask is needed when [Reactjs can handle GET and POST requests](https://malcoded.com/posts/react-http-requests-axios/).

To bring some context behind why this question is important for me: At work, we build web apps where a customer/user inputs some data (e.g. favourite food). This data is then processed using python libraries and scripts and then an output (e.g. recipe for the food) is returned to the user.

Why might Flask with React be better than React by itself?

Comment: react is a front end library, flask is a backend. react can make request, but to what?

Comment: @Nullman React can take the data from the user. That data can be processed with the python scripts. And the output can then be returned to the user. It doesn't look like Flask is needed. I am quite new to this stuff but am I missing something?

Comment: In other words, even if you don't need to keep user inputs inside a database (in which case you have to have a backend), you are going to need to have some kind of backend that is receiving those user inputs and runs the python scripts you mentioned and sends the results back to your react app.

Comment: since react runs in your browser and python is not, react will have to pass data to python somehow, so python needs to know to listen to http(s) requests, that is a server. flask is one way to handling a server in python

Comment: You can basically remove React from the question: when creating a backend / REST API, why is Python + Flask better than just Python? Put this way, the answer is simple: flask is a web framework that takes all the tedious HTTP processing off your hands.

Comment: @n1rna Can't React send the user data to the python script or alternatively can't python collect the data that the react app retrieved?

Comment: Look, to handle the client's (React's) HTTP requests server-side, you can either a) write a fully-fledged web server in python _yourself_ or b) not reinvent the wheel by using flask

Comment: You need a connection between these two, usually people use HTTP as the protocol between frontend and backend components. So basically you need a http server as your backend (its a layer between user input and python scripts)

Comment: @ChrisG the question was Flask+React vs React not Flask vs React. Apologies if that wasnt clear in the question

Comment: @n1rna Okay I think I'm building the picture now. Is there a link that you can provide that explains it further?

Comment: @ChrisG to be honest. Even though I don't need React and just need Flask. I want to use React to build a prettier frontend and because React is a good skill to learn.

Comment: Not sure how to put this so you understand, so let me try again: whether you use React on the client-side has **ZERO** bearing on whether you use flask on the server-side. You are asking why people are using flask when React already supports GET and POST requests, but that question doesn't make _any_ sense. Because React is client-side (frontend) and flask is server-side (backend). The two are not two alternative solutions, they are two different animals entirely.

Comment: @ChrisG thanks. Could post an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React and flask are two separate solutions for different problems. In the context of a REST API, flask (on top of python) can be used to *provide* the API. React on the other hand is a client-side framework and is thus at best indirectly involved in *consuming* it.

Neither React nor flask is needed, both are independent convenience frameworks. React for the JavaScript client-side, flask for the Python server-side.

React makes it easier to provide an HTML interface to the user, flask makes it easier to reply to incoming HTTP requests on the server.

Answer (score 1):

React is just a javascript library which helps in building user interfaces, whereas flask is a microframework for building web applications.
Handling http requests in the context of React means that it can make http requests and make decisions based on what they output. React does not have control over the business logic i.e the way the requests are going to get processed, which in your case is deciding recipe based on user's input. That's where flask or a backend comes into picture, it would take the input given by the frontend, do some processing and return some output. Over here http is just a medium of passing information from frontend to the backend.

To understand these concepts a bit more you could research more on the MVC architecture.